# How to load input for NN in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, toolbox

I want to use **NN toolbox** in `matlab`
my input is a `42*3` and my target is `42*1`
i Have 42 `samples` with 3 `features`
but *I cant load the target and it hasn't any error but it doesn't load*
can anyone help me

Comment: Please show your code for loading the target data. If you don't get any error, what is happening to show that the data is not loaded?

Comment: I use toolbox when I browse input, input loaded and show it. when I broswe the target it doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

Try to load an example dataset first. Matlab provides six example data sets, you can choose in the GUI. If you have no problems with those, the problem is with your data.

Comment: Thank you I solved my problem. I should put my target in a 42*4 matrix. It's a zeros matrix with 1 where the target is true